# Constraints on struct values

Tags: racket

I want to define a `point` struct and check that `(x, y)` satisfies the equation `y^2 = x^3 + ax + b`.

```
(struct point (x y a b) #:transparent)

(define on-curve (point 3 -7 5 7))    ; (1)

(define off-curve (point -2 4 5 7))   ; (2)
```

(1) Should work because `-7^2 = 3^3 + 5*3 + 7`

(2) Should raise an error because `4^2 != -2^3 + 5*3 + 7`

I know I need some kind of contract but I'm stuck figuring out how to do it ....

Answer (score 6):

There's a keyword argument named `#:guard` that does this:

```
(struct point (x y a b)
  #:transparent
  #:guard (λ (x y a b name)
            (unless (= (* y y) (+ (* x x x) (* a x) b))
              (error 'point "not a valid point"))
            (values x y a b)))

(point 3 -7 5 7) ;=> (point 3 -7 5 7)
(point -2 4 5 7) ;=> point: not a valid point
```

See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html for an example (`celsius`). See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/creatingmorestructs.html for the full description of the guard function.